# How to create duplicate rows based on some conditions?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, datatable, datarow

My Datatable has some columns that contains data in the format as 2011~|~2012~|~2013. Now the table has only one row. But based on how many such data is there, that many rows should be created

Hence, in the above format, three rows should be created each having Year column filled as 2011, 2012 and 2013. It doesn't matter that if other columns are being duplicated

Format similar to Year column also exists for some 2-3 more columns such as Sales column states figures as 190~|~250~|~488.

One Important Note: The number of rows here should be 3 (considering year & sales column). It should not be 9 (3 x 3). There is a one-to-one relationship, say in year 2011 sales was 190mn$, for 2012 it was 250 mn$ and for 2013 expected is 488mn$.

The below image explains more in detail.

I guess the funda is cleared. If not, let me know.

Please guide

[image: Image Added]

Comment: Please could you provide some sample code/data

Comment: @curt: I wish to provide the whole excel sheet which makes question very clear. is there any way to upload in SO?

Comment: Perhaps just attach a screenshot showing the columns with some sample data. I don't think you can upload Excel to SO

Comment: Supportive image added. Hope you (& all supportive guys) could see it

Comment: @Curt: Awaiting your inputs as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
private DataTable AlterDataTable(DataTable oldTable)
{
    DataTable newTable = oldTable.Clone();
    foreach (DataRow row in oldTable.Rows)
    {
        var years = row["Year"]
        .ToString()
        .Split(new string[] { "~|~" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .ToList();
        foreach (var year in years)
        {
            row["Year"] = year;
            newTable.ImportRow(row);
        }

    }

    return newTable;
}
```

Call it as `DataTable dataTable = AlterDataTable(dt);`

For this requirement, try this

```
private DataTable AlterDataTable(DataTable oldTable)
{
    DataTable newTable = oldTable.Clone();
    foreach (DataRow row in oldTable.Rows)
    {
        var years = row["Year"]
        .ToString()
        .Split(new string[] { "~|~" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .ToList();
        var sales = row["Sales"]
        .ToString()
        .Split(new string[] { "~|~" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .ToList();
        if (years.Count != sales.Count)
        {
            throw new Exception("Argument count mismatch exception");
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < years.Count; i++)
        {
            row["Year"] = years[i];
            row["Sales"] = sales[i];
            newTable.ImportRow(row);
        }
    }
    return newTable;
}
```

Please note that the splits should be having the same count.

Comment: let me try this!.. fingers crossed!

Comment: that didn't worked! What the code did was that, it kept only one column as Year with data of first column in it (and not the year as 2011 etc). Remaining columns got removed with data.

Comment: But what to do if i have 3-4 more columns similar to year column?

Comment: just give me a hint..i wish to try.. if not.. another question would be posted in SO..! :-)

Comment: usage of inner loop doubles the number of rows. Instead of 3 rows, it creates 6 rows

Comment: Thanks naveen for the inputs. but i need 3 rows only as all the columns would have same number of format ie same like year.

Comment: Hello naveen, it would be very helpful if you could just give your inputs regarding showing 3 rows. thanks!

Comment: i too agree that it is bit odd, but that is the way it should work... :-(

Comment: I have edited my question. Is that sufficient or a new question is required?

Comment: please delete your comments. have updated code. too much comments. that why :)